# Find $ \lim_{x\to 0^+ } \frac{\alpha(x)}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function with $f'(0)\neq 0$. Let $x>0$ and define $$ \int_{0}^x f(u) du = f(\alpha) x  $$
where $\alpha=\alpha(x)$ is a number in $[0,x]$.

Find $$ \lim_{x\to 0^+ } \frac{\alpha(x)}{x}.$$

I tried some ideas: First of all

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \alpha(x)=0. $$

$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac {\alpha(x)}{x}$ takes the indeterminate form.

If I keep going like this I get the limit is $\alpha'(x)$.
I get the same result if I apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and mean value theorem assuming $F$ as the primitive of $f$. But I think what have I done is not quite correct because I never used $f'(0)\neq 0 $.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why should $\alpha$ be a linear function of $x$?

Comment: Can not we express any $\alpha$ in $[0,x]$ in term of $x$? I am little doubtful.

Comment: You can express it in terms of $x$, but it need not be linear. It could as easily be $|\sin(x)|$.

Comment: Yes, that make sense.

Comment: Take the Taylor expansion of $f$, and integrate that.

Comment: I can't quite parse your question even if others don't seem to have a difficulty. What exactly are you defining with that equality? If you divide both sides by $x$ then $\dfrac1x\int_{0}^x f(u) du = f(\alpha)$ so here the LHS is the average value of $f$ over $[0,x]$. Are you saying we define $\alpha(x)$ so that $f$ evaluated at $\alpha(x)$ is exactly said average value? That is $\dfrac1x\int_{0}^x f(u) du = f(\alpha(x))$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(\alpha(x))=f(0)+f'(0)\alpha(x)+o(\alpha(x))=f(0)+f'(0)\alpha(x)+o(x) \quad\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\quad\Rightarrow\frac{\alpha(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{f'(0)}\frac{f(\alpha(x))-f(0)}{x}+o(1)\quad\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\alpha(x)}{x}=\frac{1}{f'(0)}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(\alpha(x))-f(0)}{x}=\frac{1}{f'(0)}\lim_{x\to 0^+}
\frac{\int_0^xf(u)\,du-f(0)x}{x^2}=
$$
$$
=[\text{L'Hospital two times}]=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f'(x)}{2f'(0)}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

P.S. Geometrically, if you look at what happens very close to $0$ you can imagine that the graph $y=f(x)$ is nearly a line with constant slope $f'(0)$, and the integral is the area of the right angled trapezoid from $0$ to $x$ with $\alpha$ being in the middle of $[0,x]$, thus approximately $x/2$.

Comment: This is perfect. I had kind of intuition but I should have expand near $\alpha(x)$ then only I could get the expression $\frac{\alpha(x)}{x}$.

Comment: why is $o(\alpha(x))=o(x)$?

Comment: Because $0 \leq \alpha(x) \leq x$ by definition.

Comment: @user251257 $\alpha\in[0,x]$.

Comment: so, yes. thx @A.G.